Copy column of PySpark Levenshtein distances into upper/lower triangular array without Python looping
I am following this example to generate 450+ million Levenshtein distances between 30,011 text labels of up to 20 characters.  The problem is that the distance values are organized into a single column.  I need them in the form of a lower or upper triangular matrix.  A nested loop to copy them would be too slow.  How can I accomplish this without incurring the slowness of Python looping?
Prior to using PySpark, I used Python Levenshtein in a nested Python loop.  It's far too slow (1.5 hours).  Replacing the distance calculation with a menial task like min(String1,String2) reduces the time just a little, so I assume that most of the 1.5 hours is for looping rather than calculation.
